# When to call Javascript for ScrollHeight

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe, postmessage

I have a page with an iframe. The two sites (parent site is php, child site is asp.net 2.0) are on different domains, although I control both of them. Most of the work is done within the iframe. I am using the postMessage function to send information about the total height of the content in the iframe. However, it always comes up as 0, I guess because the script executes before everything is laid out on the screen. Is there a way I can obtain the total height (I think it's scrollHeight, right?) of the child site so that I can send it to the parent?

Thanks!

Comment: someone made a article on it [LINK](http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes). hope this helps. Else try adding the listener inside "document ready"[LINK](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: That article actually got me started with this whole thing. But the problem is that I'm working only in the iframe, moving from page to page within the iframe. Sending a message from the parent frame asking the iframe for it's size would only work on the initial load of the page containing the iframe, unless I ask the parent frame to refresh each time I go to another page in the iframe (which I'd rather not do).

Comment: so you want to listen to events from the iframe.. there is a trick for that. ill write it as an answer as its too big for a comment

Comment: I already have a listener on the parent frame and I get the message. My problem is that the iframe sends a value of 0.

Comment: hmm. you sure you are passing the correct height from the trigger? something like this 'parent.$(parent.document).trigger("atriggerMessage", document.body.clientHeight);' then you can extract the height required and work with it... if this fails too try  making a jsfiddle will make it easier to debug

Comment: Where in my child site would I call this?

Comment: when ever you want the parent to adjust the iframe size.. from your above comment it seems like " go to another page in the iframe". so every time a page is loaded in the iframe fire the trigger... that's basically inside very 'dom ready' function of your child pages

Comment: I think perhaps I caused some confusion. I have no problem sending the message. My problem is that the child height in the message (and even standalone with an alert function) always comes up as 0. And I put the code in the window.onload event. I just tried it in $(document).ready and it is giving me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

so you want the parent to adjust the size of iFrame when you got o another page etc.. so suppose your using jquery as the JS lib you can try this trick. in the parent.html do this

```
$(document).bind('atriggerMessage', function(e) {
      //do the iframe size change or other stuff
});
```

then within the iframe you need to trigger the event. so in the iframe.html

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger("atriggerMessage");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my solution in case someone else comes across the same issue.

I ended up putting javascript code in the html markup almost right before the closing  tag. This ensured that the page was visible before the body.scrollHeight was called. I don't understand why the body.scrollHeight inside window.onload() or body.onload or $(document).ready() as @shakirthow said above.